# Zimage is too large comparing to stock kernel

Tags: android, linux-kernel, arm, kernel, cross-compiling

I am trying to update kernel for my SM-t365 using device source code at http://opensource.samsung.com. I have done the following steps to get the zImage file:

- Extract the Kernel.tar.gz to kernel folder
- Install eabi-4.7 tool chains
- Change nothing and execute build_kernel.sh

The build process is successful and I can find the zImage file at `kernel/arch/arm/boot/`, but the size for my kernel is too big (18.09 MB) compared to the stock kernel size (8.50 MB).

I created a new boot.img file and tried to update the kernel using Odin v3.07.
Odin v3.07 returned error with FAIL (Size).

What I have done wrong so far? How can I reduce my kernel size to the same as stock roms?

Comment: The actual compressed kernel image resides in `{KERNEL_ROOT_DIR}/output/arch/arm/boot/` it's named "zImage" and should be about 8 to 9 MB in size, what you currently have is the "Image" file (I'm guessing about 20 MB in size), this one is uncompressed and is copied to source dir of `"arch/arm/boot"`. The compressed kernel image starts with "z" I.e. the "zImage" file.

Comment: After building this zImage file, you won't have the wifi driver (blame Samsung). boot.img can be flashed by custom recovery or a tar.md5 file can be flashed by odin. I'm currently stuck at this boot image stage, it doesn't boot up past the Samsung logo. I'm building for 'SM-E700H' by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have found your model on samsung open source, google the code of the kernal and find the matching stock rom on samfirm.  You can flash the compiled kernal without wifi or other issues.